# How to access from host (Windows) access VPN connection established inside of guest machine (Ubuntu)

Tags: networking, vpn, gateway, cisco

There's a **Cisco AnyConnect** client buried inside of VirtualBox' **guest machine (Ubuntu)** which is setting up a VPN connection to my work network.

I'm trying to access my work network from the **host Windows** but I can't figure out how to do it.

Once I establish VPN connection in guest OS, Cisco client adds a route to work network **10.0.0.0** and DNS **10.66.68.70**.

What I've done so far:

- I added two LAN interfaces to the VM (1. Host-only Adapter; 2. Bridged Adapter)
- I enabled IP forwarding in guest OS (nano /etc/resolv.conf; net.ipv4.ip_forward=1)
- I added route config from host OS to guest OS:
  route add -p 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 192.168.56.1
  where 192.168.56.1 is IP of the guest OS.
- I tried to add DNS in the host OS but it returned an error:

`netsh interface ip set dns "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" static 10.66.68.70`

`The configured DNS server is incorrect or does not exist.`

I can access guest machine by its ip (for example, Apache is working http://192.168.56.101:80/)

But I can't access work network by accessing any of 10.x.x.x addresses.

How do I manage to access VPN resources from my host OS?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to route your linux host via the guest os since your host's source IP addresses will not be routed back by the VPN remote end. However you may be able to proxy connection either via a regular proxy or you may be able to run and SSH server and use that as a proxy.

You can also run an anyconnect client on your linux and just connect to your remote network directly. See [openconnect](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) project.

I have created a quick and dirty dockerfile to connect to anyconnect remote ends with a simple docker container. The container runs a proxy and an SSH server and I can pretty much proxy anything I want.
See it [here](https://github.com/ucipass/dockerfiles/tree/master/openconnect).